# Issue calling a MySQL stored procedure (with params) via a linked server (SQL Server 2005) using OPENQUERY syntax

Tags: mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures, linked-list

I'm having issues when trying to call a MySQL (5.0.77) stored procedure with parameters, via a linked server (SQL Server 2005) using the OPENQUERY syntax.

The MySQL stored procedure returns a result set, and when I use the 'EXEC ... AT ...' syntax the call works fine, e.g...

```
EXEC('CALL my_stored_proc(''2009-10-07'',''2009-10-07'');') AT MySQLSERVER;
```

The limitation of using 'EXEC ... AT ...' means I can't insert the result set into a temporary table in SQL Server, which is ultimately what I want to do. Which led me to trying the OPENQUERY syntax...

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MySQLSERVER,'CALL my_stored_proc(''2009-10-07'',''2009-10-07'');')
```

...But this fails, and returns...

```
 Msg 7357, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
 Cannot process the object "CALL my_stored_proc(''2009-10-07'',''2009-10-07'');". The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MySQLSERVER" indicates that either the object has no columns or the current user does not have permissions on that object.
```

Which is strange, given that the 'EXEC ... AT ...' call didn't complain about permissions. The following calls all work fine...

```
EXEC('SHOW TABLES;') AT MySQLSERVER;

SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MySQLSERVER,'SHOW TABLES;');

CREATE TABLE #tmpTest (
    [table] varchar(255) null
);
INSERT INTO #tmpTest ([table])
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MySQLSERVER,'SHOW TABLES;');
SELECT * FROM #tmpTest;
DROP TABLE #tmpTest;
```

So my question is, how can I make a call to a MySQL stored procedure, via a linked server, and store the result set in a temporary table in SQL Server? Either by using the 'EXEC ... AT ...' syntax, or by solving the object/permissions error when using the OPENQUERY syntax.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to enable "**Ad Hoc Distributed Queries**" on the SQL Server. This is not enabled by default, for security reasons. Most of the time, the "do not have permission" errors are related to this one.

Execute this on the SQL Server, and then try again your code:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
EXEC sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1;
GO
RECONFIGURE;
GO
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

I tried the fix to configure "Ad Hoc Distributed Queries" but was still getting this same error:

- "The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "MyMySQL" indicates
  that either the object has no columns or the current user does not
  have permissions on that object."

I am attempting a simple remote SELECT query against a linked MySQL database.
In my case, the query I was attempting looked like this.  Pay attention to the number of lines used:

```
SELECT * FROM  OPENQUERY
([MyMySQL], 
'
SELECT
ID as ISSUE_ID, etc..
```

The fix was to remove the newline after the opening single-quote.  Simple, huh?  But not obvious.

The working code shown below:

```
SELECT * FROM  OPENQUERY
([MyMySQL], 
'SELECT
ID as ISSUE_ID, etc..
```

Hope it helps!
Rob

Answer (score 0):

I realize this a pretty old post, but my problem was similar to Rob's in that the SQL within the OPENQUERY doesn't take line breaks as whitespace the same way SQL server does.

i.e. Laying out my query as follows:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    OPENQUERY(LINKEDSERVER, '
        SELECT
            SomeField
        FROM
            SomeTable
    ')
```

I *needed* to have spaces as if it were written on one line (using _ as a visible space for demonstration):

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    OPENQUERY(LINKEDSERVER, '
        SELECT_
            SomeField_
        FROM_
            SomeTable
    ')
```